# Differentiating a Bessel function with Lambda

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, sympy

I am trying to make a list of n derivatives (with n the order) of a Bessel function. I use the Bessel function from scipy.special:

```
import sympy as sp
import scipy.special as sc

x = sp.Function('x')
t = sp.symbols('t')
n = 10
f = lambda x: sc.jv(0,2j*sp.sqrt(x))
deriv_list = [x(t), f(x(t))]  # list of derivatives [x(t), x'(t), x''(t),...]

for i in range(1,n):
    df_i = deriv_list[-1].diff(t).replace(sp.Derivative,lambda *args: f(x(t)))
    deriv_list.append(df_i)
```

This however gives the TypeError that ufunc 'jv' is not supported for the input types. Apparently sc.jv cannot handle lambda functions.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Full error message please

Comment: You need to use sympy's symbolic besseli function rather than scipy's numeric jv function.